Flutter validatate email addresses
I am reading Chapter 6 of the Flutter Cookbook - Second Edition by Simone Alessandria, and I am trying to implement email validation in the login_screen.dart file as demonstrated in the book. However, the email validation does not seem to work as expected.
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'stopwatch.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/login';
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool loggedIn = false;
  String name = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: loggedIn ? _buildSuccess() : _buildLoginForm(),
      ),
    );

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _emailController.dispose();
      _nameController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildSuccess() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.orangeAccent),
        Text('Hi $name')
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoginForm() {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Runner'),
                  validator: (text) =>
                      text!.isEmpty ? 'Enter the runner\'s name.' : null,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _emailController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                  validator: (text) {
                    if (text!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter the runner\'s email.';
                    }
                    final regex = RegExp('[^@]+@[^.]+..+');
                    if (!regex.hasMatch(text)) {
                      return 'Enter a valid email';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _validate,
                  child: const Text('Continue'),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }

  void _validate() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form?.validate() ?? false) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      loggedIn = true;
      name = _nameController.text;
    });
  }
}

The email validation logic is supposed to ensure that the email input matches the regex pattern [^@]+@[^.]+..+. However, when I run the app, even invalid email addresses are being accepted.
The full code can be found on the author's GitHub
Could someone help me identify why the email validation is not working as expected? Any guidance on what might be wrong or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

No, please don't use this regex to validate email.  It's wrong.  The shortest regex to validate an RFC822 email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.

Please check your _validate() method you have apply wrong if condition form?.validate() ?? false change it as per below
  void _validate() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form!.validate() == false) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      loggedIn = true;
      name = _nameController.text;
    });
  }

== Operator: The == operator is used for equality two conditions. It checks two values are equal.
?? Operator: The ?? operator is a null-aware operator,It checks the value is null or not.
Note: form?.validate() == false this also working.
